# How to initialize reactive form values inside of a modal component?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

See example plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/97nXCbQ5quCg7hVRjMvk?p=info

As you can see in `app.ts` in `showModal()` I'm opening an instance of a modal with my `DialogComponent` then calling `modalRef.componentInstance.myModel = { name: 'Hello!' };` which I expect should trigger the `ngOnChanges()` function in `src/dialog-component.ts` which should then set the form values, which should show the new value of "Hello!" in the Name form field.

However, it looks like `ngOnChanges()` isn't being triggered at all so this never happens.

What am I getting wrong here? I want to be able to open the modal and have it pre-populated with the values taken from the `myModel` data model.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your value is changed on InInit

so if you do this

```
 ngOnInit(){
     if(this.myModel){
        this.rebuildForm();

     }
    }
```

in your dialog component you should be able to achieve what you are trying.

http://plnkr.co/edit/I3bE04IVrVby1I77GnIX?p=preview